# JAVA: how to pass an object within one object to another object?

Tags: java, object

I need to pass an object (for example object from Class DATA) which is within another object (for example object from Class NODE) to another object (from class NODE)?
The Node objects are nodes of a tree. The tree implementation is :

```
public class Tree {

private Node rootElement;

public Tree() {
    super();
}

public Node getRootElement() {
    return this.rootElement;
}

public void setRootElement(Node rootElement) {
    this.rootElement = rootElement;
}
```

and then for Node I have:

```
public class Node {

public MyNode data;
public List<Node> children;
public int  childNo;  

public Node() {
    super();
}

public Node(MyNode data) {
    this();
    setData(data);
}

 public Node(MyNode data, int childNo) {
    this();
    setData(data);
    this.childNo=childNo;
}

public void setChildren(List<Node> children) {
    this.children = children;
}

public void addChild(Node child) {
    if (children == null) {
        children = new ArrayList<Node>();
    }
    children.add(child);
}

public MyNode getData() {
    return this.data;
}

public void setData(MyNode data) {
    this.data = data;
}
```

and for Mynode I have :

```
public class MyNode {

public String ID = new String();   //UUID
protected String parentID;
MyNodesDATA d = new MyNodesDATA();


public MyNode() {
    setID(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
}

public MyNodesDATA getMyNodesDATA () {
    return this.MyNodesDATA ;
}

public void setData(MyNodesDATA d) {
    this.MyNodesDATA = data;
}
```

and this is MyNodesDATA

```
public class MyNodesDATA {
int iD;
String name;
}
```

So each node of the tree has an object of MyNode Type and each MyNode Object has a data as an object from MyNodesDATA class. I have already initialised the tree with a predefined structures of hierarchical nodes using some recursive methods which I didn't put here ... 
Now, nodes of the tree in lover levels process their data and need to send them to their parents (USING THEIR PARENT ID). I stuck here... how a node (an object) can send it's data to another node (another object) (let say its parent in this scenario) using only one ID variable of the other object ... in a simpler way I need a method to get (ID and DATA) and send the data to the object which has the ID !! and of course there should be another function or event handler in receiver side to take action once receives a Data ....

Comment: If I'm understanding your new question correctly what you require is a function to search the tree for a given id? The simplest way to do this would be to start at the root and recurse down each child in order, assuming there's no sorting. What have you tried so far for a search function?

Comment: See [this wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal) for info on different tree traversal algorithms if this is where you're stuck.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you probably want to make the `DATA` instance created in the `Node` constructor an instance member. Otherwise it can be released by the garbage collector once the constructor is done.

Then can either pass the `DATA` parameter to a constructor of `Node`, or you can have a setter method that would accept a `DATA` parameter.

```
public class Node {
    int iD;
    private DATA d;

    public Node(){
        this.d = new DATA(); // or this(new DATA());
    }

    public Node(DATA d){
        this.d = d;
    }

    public void setData (DATA d) {
        this.d = d;
    }

    public DATA getData() {
        return this.d;
    }
}
```

Now you have several options for 2 `Node` instances to share the `DATA` member :

```
public class MAIN {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DATA data = new DATA();
        Node node1 = new Node(data);
        Node node2 = new Node(data);
    }
}
```

or

```
public class MAIN {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Node node1 = new Node();
        Node node2 = new Node(node1.getData());
    }
}
```

or

```
public class MAIN {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Node node1 = new Node();
        Node node2 = new Node(null);
        node2.setData (node1.getData());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your example, `Node` does **not** have an object of `DATA` within it; you've simply initialised one in the constructor then allowed it to go out of scope. You also need to modify your constructor if you want to pass in a `DATA` object, so change `Node` to be:

```
public class Node {
    int iD;
    DATA d;
    public Node(){
        d = new DATA();
    }
    public Node(DATA d){
        this.d = d;
    }
}
```

so that you have the `DATA` instance stored. Then simply provide a getter, e.g.:

```
public DATA getData() {
    return d;
}
```

and then you can do:

```
public class MAIN {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Node node1 = new Node();
        Node node2 = new Node(node1.getData());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks you are right I forgot to declare a DATA object in Node object. actually my code is more complicated than this one. I have several objects which are not declared and initialized like "Node node1 = new Node();" so I don't have references like node1 for my objects.. but my objects has got an ID .. I want to pass DATA using the ID's of Node objects ....

Comment: Actually my Nodes are inside a tree structure ... so I want to pass the data of one Node of the tree to another node of the tree ...

Comment: so you want to search a tree for a node by id then get the DATA object from that node and pass it into another node in the tree also found by id? if so that's a totally different question :P

Comment: actually each node contains its parent ID and an array list of its children .. so a child node wants to send its data to its parent and vice versa  ..

Comment: you'll need to update your question with how you've implemented your tree and what you're having difficulty with, i'm not really sure why you require nodes in a tree to sync their data in that manner... you'll need to write a method that searches the tree for a matching node and returns it; it depends if you're looking for a node with that id or a node which has a child node with that id what that method would look like. Then you can set the data whichever direction you want using getters and setters.